# define analyzer globally (ES)

Tags: elasticsearch

I need/want to define my custom analyzers globally. therefore I edited the configuration file of ES (elasticsearch.yml) according to this answer: [Can I customize Elastic Search to use my own Stop Word list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927629/can-i-customize-elastic-search-to-use-my-own-stop-word-list/13012458#13012458) the relevant entries are

```
index.analysis.analyzer.angram:
  type: custom
  tokenizer: standard
  filter: standard, lowercase, fngram
index.analysis.filter.fngram:
  type: nGram
  min_gram: 2
  max_gram: 10
```

but when I try to invoke `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=angram' -d 'this is a test'` I get an `ElasticSearchIllegalARgumentException[failed to find analyzer [angram]]`.

is the configuration wrong? (although I'd expect ES to not start-up when encountered an error when reading the configuration during start-up)

how do I correctly define an analyzer globally?

**EDIT:**
I'm using version 0.90.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was with the URL in the `curl` statement. credit goes to Ivan ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/5XlUoghKURg )

I'm quoting his answer from the group:

> You cannot use a custom analyzer until it is referenced by an index. You would need to create a mapping that uses the analyzer and then use that index in the analyzer call. There is no need to index any documents to that index.
>
> `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/SOMEINDEX/_analyze?analyzer=angram'`

Comment: in this case, you need to create the analyzer first since *angram* is a custom analyzer. Other build-in analyzer such as Standard, or whitespace, no need to be created.