# ElasticSearch Global Analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to define a global analyzer in ElasticSearch. I edited the configuration file of ES (elasticsearch.yml)

```
index :
   analysis :        
      analyzer :            
         myTestAnalyzer :                
            type : standard
            max_token_length : 50
```

and restarted the service.

When i run in Sense

```
GET /_analyze?analyzer=myTestAnalyzer
{"This is a test"}
```

I get

{
   "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to find analyzer [myTestAnalyzer]]",
   "status": 400
}

I have read in another post ([define analyzer globally (ES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913073/define-analyzer-globally-es)) that I need to create a mapping that uses the analyzer and then use that index in the analyzer call.

Can you please give me an example how to do that.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you would add the mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test_index/test/_mapping' -d '
{
    "test": {
        "properties": {
            "myField": {"type": "string"}
        },
    "analyzer": "myTestAnalyzer"
    }
}'
```

Instead of `analyzer` you could also use `search_analyzer` and `index_analyzer` if you want to specify different analyzers for search and index. (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html#_index_search_analyzers)