# Selectively turn off stop words in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

So I would like to turn off stop word filtering on the `username`, `title`, and `tags` fields but not the `description` field.

As you can imagine I do not want to filter out a result called `the best` but I do want to stop `the` from affecting the score if it is in the `description` field (search `the` on GitHub if you want an example).

Now @Javanna says ( [Is there a way to "escape" ElasticSearch stop words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883936/is-there-a-way-to-escape-elasticsearch-stop-words) ):

> In your case I would disable stopwords for that specific field rather than modifying the stopword list, but you could do the latter too if you wish to.

Failing to provide an example so I searched around and tried the `common` query: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/stop-stopping-stop-words-a-look-at-common-terms-query/ which didn't work for me either.

So I searched for specifically stopping the filtering stop words however the closest I have come to is stopping it index wide: [Can I customize Elastic Search to use my own Stop Word list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927629/can-i-customize-elastic-search-to-use-my-own-stop-word-list) by attacking the analyzer directly, or failing that the documentation hints at making my own analyzer `:/`.

What is the best way selectively disable stop words on certain fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already know what to do, which would be to customize your analyzers for certain fields. From what I understand you did not manage to create a valid syntax example for that. This is what we used in a project, I hope that this example points you in the right direction:

```
  {
    :settings => {
      :analysis => {
        :analyzer => {
          :analyzer_umlauts => {
            :tokenizer    => "standard",
            :char_filter  => ["filter_umlaut_mapping"],
            :filter       => ["standard", "lowercase"],
          }
        },
        :char_filter => {
          :filter_umlaut_mapping => {
            :type => 'mapping',
            :mappings_path => es_config_file("char_mapping")
          }
        }
      }
    },
    :mappings => {
      :company => {
        :properties => {
          [...]
          :postal_city => { :type => "string",  :analyzer => "analyzer_umlauts", :omit_norms => true, :omit_term_freq_and_positions => true, :include_in_all => false },
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sweet it does I'll test it tomorrow when I am back and mark it thanks :)